# TFTP Server working, PXE Boot is not

Tags: networking, linux-networking, pxe-boot

We have set up a TFTP server in Debian and want to set up a PXE boot server. Currently the problem is that while we can retrieve files using TFTP, the PXE boot agent can not retrieve the file.

Successful TFTP transfer:
`21:49:09.405200 IP client.55574 > server.tftp:  22 RRQ "pxelinux.0" netascii`

Failed PXE boot:
`21:50:29.823916 IP client.1038 > server.tftp:  40 RRQ "pxelinux.0" octet tsize 0 blksize 1468`

On the PXE boot client machine, we see:

```
>>Media Present.....
>>Start PXE over IPV4.
Station IP Address is 123.123.123.123.

Server IP address is 123.123.123.1
NBP filename is pxelinux.0
NBP file size is 0 Bytes
PXE-E99: Unexpected network error
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any PXE booting, but the issue I hit was the tftp server not being 100% compatible with the PXE client which if often REALLY simple. If you can try switching to `atftpd` if you're server is linux

Answer (score 0):

OK:

> 21:49:09.405200 IP client.55574 >
> server.tftp:  22 RRQ "pxelinux.0" **netascii**

Failed:

> 21:50:29.823916 IP client.1038 > server.tftp:  40 RRQ
> "pxelinux.0" **octet** tsize 0 blksize 1468

The TFTP transfer of PXE components i.e. NBPs like pxelinux.0 should always be type **octet** and not **netascii**
From your post it looks the first transfer should be the one that fails and the second one the one that succeeds